# deleting all messages from a certain month using from_logs generator

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have messages from a certain month (August) that I want to get rid of using my bot as a test, I looked around the Internet and documentation and encountered this code:

```
@Client.command(pass_context = True)
async def clear(ctx, number, around):
    mgs = []
    number = int(number)
    async for x in Client.logs_from(ctx.message.channel, limit = number, around = datetime):
        mgs.append(x)
    await Client.delete_messages(mgs)
```

I looked at the documentation to see what logs_from does and it seems to be exactly what I need because it has the around argument which will allow me to return messages from August, the problem is I can't seem to figure out in what form to put the `timedate` in if that makes sense, how could I specify August?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`around` is a little fuzzier than what you're looking for.  I recommend you use `before` and `after` instead:

```
from datetime import datetime

def around_month(month, year):
    begin = datetime.strptime(f'1 {month} {year}', '%d %b %Y')
    if begin.month == 12:
        end = datetime(begin.year+1, 1, 1)
    else:
        end = datetime(begin.year, begin.month+1, 1)
    return begin, end

@Client.command(pass_context = True)
async def clear(ctx, number: int, month, year):
    mgs = []
    begin, end = around_month(month, year)
    async for x in Client.logs_from(ctx.message.channel, limit = number, after=begin, before=end):
        mgs.append(x)
    await Client.delete_messages(mgs)
```

So to delete messages from augist, you would invoke this command like

```
!clear 100 AUG 2018
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be finding any messages, I go back to August and everything is still there, is the parameters on the command wrong or something? I also have a counter that adds on on the for loop and then print it after the loop to confirm this, it's 0...

Comment: On second thought, I have it print the counter during the loop on the console just in case, and it doesn't do it so, the only explonation I can find for this is if it skips the for loop altogether, im clueless as to what the problem is at this point

Comment: @Myronaz Sorry I had a typo, try with `end = datetime(begin.year, begin.month+1, 1)` instead.  I fixed the code in the answer too.

Comment: Alright... so... because i'm trying to delete messages from August, it sends a Bad request error because I can't 'Bulk delete them' since they are more than 14 days old which means that I have to delete each one separately inside the loop, like `await client.delete_messages(x)` which works but after one message it throws a `Message Object is not iterable` exception, here is the error log: https://pastebin.com/gC71YKJx and updated code: https://pastebin.com/Jf0NpsPj

Comment: @Myronaz `delete_message` not `delete_messages`

Comment: Ah I see, I can't believe I didn't spot this, thank you so much for your help